# How to unit test that a function has been decorated?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-decorators

I have a view that is decorated like this:

```
@check_has_permission('is_manager')
def view():
   pass
```

and the decorator looks something like this:

```
def check_has_permission(group=None):
    def can_user_access(user):
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if group == 'is_staff':
                return user.is_staff()
            elif group == 'is_admin':
                return (
                    user.is_admin() or
                    user.is_staff()
                )
            elif group == 'is_manager':
                return (
                    user.is_manager() or
                    user.is_admin() or
                    user.is_staff()
                )
        return False
    return user_passes_test(can_user_access, login_url=login_url)
```

How do I write a unit test to confirm the view is decorated with check_has_permission with a group of 'is_manager'?

I'm hoping I can write a set of tests for the decorator itself, then I only have to confirm I'm calling the right group for each view it decorates.

Comment: Wat is `check_has_permission` exactly?

Comment: Don't test that the view has been decorated, that's too meta.  Instead: login the django client with generated users.  Test that a manager user gets HTTP 200 OK at that view, and a non manager user gets an HTTP 403.

Comment: @wim I reuse the decorator a lot so if like to test it once instead of all the variations on each view.

Comment: Your decorator has a different name in each snippet. I assume they're supposed to be named the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a *seam* where you can test.

If your decorator looks like this:

```
def is_user_in_group(group):
    if user.is_authenticated():
        # ... snip - checks on groups and user ...

    return False


def check_has_permission(group=None):
    def can_user_access(user):
        return is_user_in_group(user, group)
    return user_passes_test(can_user_access, login_url=login_url)
```

Then your test can mock both `is_user_in_group` and `user_passes_test`, call the decorated function, test that `is_user_in_group` gets called with the correct group, and test that `user_passes_test` gets called with the return value from your mock of `is_user_in_group`.

Comment: This is almost there, but i helped me figure it out. I had to add a testable function is_user_in_group(user, group) and call that inside the can_user_access(user) function defined in check_user_access(group). Then I mocked is_user_in_group. If you make those edits, i'll mark this as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: I think this would still work, so I'd prefer to leave it as is. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question with the solution you eventually used.

Comment: I tried it out and the mock only got called at the import time. Because I have multiple views using different groups, the test only returned the last time it was called.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'll fix.

Comment: last thing would be to update `def is_user_in_group(user, group)`. I also put the is_auth logic in is_user_in_group.